# Using a backslash with occur

Tags: string, occur

How can I use `occur` (`M-s o`) to search for a string that contains a backslash, e.g. `\def`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash with another backslash.  So: `M-s o \\def`

See the [manual node on "Syntax for
Strings"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html)
for more information.