# bibtex-field-braces-alist syntax

Tags: bibtex

I'm struggling with using bibtex-field-braces-alist to format titles in Bibtex entries.  I've set this as

```
(setq bibtex-field-braces-alist
      '((("title") . ("N2O" "European"))))
```

My interpretation of the variable's documentation (below) is that this should cause bibtex-clean-entry to change the title field "Western European N2O emissions" to "Western {European} {N2O} emissions".  However, nothing happens for me :(   I have added "braces" to bibtex-entry-format:

```
(setq bibtex-entry-format '(opts-or-alts required-fields numerical-fields braces))
```

> bibtex-field-braces-alist’s value is ((("TITLE") "N2O" "European"))
> Original value was nil
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> Documentation: Alist of field regexps that C-c C-c encloses by braces.
> Each element has the form (FIELDS REGEXP), where FIELDS is a list of
> BibTeX field names and REGEXP is a regexp. Space characters in REGEXP
> will be replaced by "[ \t\n]+".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```el
(setq bibtex-field-braces-alist
      '((("title") "N2O\\|European")))
```

Rationale: a `REGEXP` is represented by a string, not a list. Here you want a regexp that will match the string "N2O" *or* the string "European". That is done with the alternation construct `\|` (see [Regexps Backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html) in the Emacs manual). Note that backslashes have to be doubled in strings that are to be read by the Lisp reader - see [this SE Emacs question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55601/re-search-forward-regex-behavior-for-or-boolean) for more details on this wrinkle.

Just tested it and it seems to work.

EDIT: In response to your comment about restarting emacs to get the change to take effect, that is one way to do it. The problem is that there is *another* variable, `bibtex-field-braces-opt`, that is set from `bibtex-field-braces-alist` after some munging, but only if that variable is `nil`. So to get the change to take effect without restarting emacs, you *also* have to change that variable:

```el
(setq bibtex-field-braces-opt nil)
```

One good way to avoid such problems would be to use `Customize` to change `bibtex-field-braces-alist`, which *should* be set up to reset the other variable when you change this one by calling `bibtex-field-re-init`, but AFAICT it is not: that should probably be reported as a bug. Ditto for `bibtex-field-strings-alist` and `bibtex-field-strings-opt`.

Comment: Thanks.  Good catch on the string/list - I think my brain skimmed "Alist of field regexps" and converted it to "A list of regexps" :)

Comment: It's also worth noting that I had to restart emacs to get the change to take effect.  Evaluating the expression in my .emacs file caused bibtex-field-braces-alist to show the new value when queried, but had no effect on bibtex-clean-entry until after a restart.